# Bash script not executing as expected on system boot

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, sysv

I have created a bash script inside **/etc/init.d** on raspbian jessie - pixel. The script is as follow:

**auto_announce**

```
#! /bin/bash
#/etc/init.d/auto_announce

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          auto_announce
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO


amixer cset numid=3 1
(cd /home/pi/vehicle_anouncement_system/ && forever start app.js) && (python /home/pi/vehicle_anouncement_system/simulation.py)
```

What I need to do is:

1. start forever on app.js: **`forever start app.js`**
2. After the forever is started, run the python script simulation.py: **`python simulation.py`**

The problem is **forever starts successfully** but the **python script doesn't run**.

When I run the above script in terminal using **`./auto_announce`** , the script works perfectly. But it isn't working perfectly on system boot.

What am I missing? Is there a way to log the output of the above script to find out what is causing the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to log. E.g. by adding some redirection in the script. But if you're using systemd I'd recommend writing a service instead, and you should get a lot of stuff for free, e.g. logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `forever start app.js` takes sometime to execute,so put some sleep before executing `python /home/pi/vehicle_anouncement_system/simulation.py`.
i.e. try `(cd /home/pi/vehicle_anouncement_system/ && forever start app.js) && (sleep 20) && (python /home/pi/vehicle_anouncement_system/simulation.py)`

Comment: That works for the startup, but why is it working without sleep when I directly run in terminal.